# coloring streamlines to and from origin vector field plot

Tags: plotting, color, vector

I wrote the simple following code to plot a given vector field:

```
rr := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
a := 0.5;
xlim = 1;
splot = StreamPlot[{
    rr^a (x (x rr + y rr + y^2))/rr^3,
    rr^a (y (x rr + y rr - x^2))/rr^3},
   {x, -xlim, xlim}, {y, -xlim, xlim},
   StreamColorFunction -> "Heat", AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];
Show[splot]
```

[image]

I would like to color the trajectories which enter and leave the origin in different colors.  For example:

[image]

Is there a simple way to do this?  Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started:

First, make a color function that uses the point $(x,y)$ and vector $(v_x,v_y)$ at that point to get the $\cos$ of the angle between the two:

```
Clear[color]
color[x_, v_] := Module[{q},
  q = x.v/(Norm[x] Norm[v]);
  Return[Blend[{Blue, Black, Red}, (q + 1)/2]]
  ]
```

**Edit**
Another color Function:

```
Clear[color]
color[x_, v_] := Module[{q, c},
Which[
  x[[1]] > 0 && x[[2]] <= 0,
  c = GrayLevel[.2]
 ,
 True,
  q = x.v/(Norm[x] Norm[v]);
 c = Blend[{Blue, Black, Red}, (q + 1)/2]
 ];
 Return[c]
 ]
```

Then use the function in your plot:

```
rr := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
a := 0.5;
xlim = 1;
splot = StreamPlot[{rr^a (x (x rr + y rr + y^2))/rr^3, 
rr^a (y (x rr + y rr - x^2))/rr^3},
     {x, -xlim, xlim}, {y, -xlim, xlim},
StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
StreamColorFunction -> (color[{#1, #2}, {#3, #4}] &), 
AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];
Show[splot]
```

[image]

You can play with the colors in the `Blend[]` function to get the look what you want.

Comment: Thank you -- this is almost exactly what I needed!  One small question, how can it be modified so that ll curves under the x-axis are blue.  I didn't describe this well, but I only want to color the exiting curves from the origin red (as in my hand-drawn picture)

Comment: You almost never need to use `Return[]`, and `Normalize[]` is built-in. Thus: `color[x_, v_] := Blend[{Blue, Black, Red}, (1 + Normalize[x].Normalize[v])/2]`. Alternatively: `color[x_, v_] := Blend[{Blue, Black, Red}, 1 - CosineDistance[x, v]/2].`

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to modify the color function to make it piecewise defined so that it follows this rule above the x-axis and below it colors everything blue?

Comment: Actually, I'd like all the vectors in the fourth quadrant to be colored gray.

Comment: I was able to do this simply by "showing" two plots, where I excluded the relevant regions.  Thanks!

Comment: I have added another verbose color function. As J.M. points out these functions can be written in a much shorter form but I leave them expanded for clarity.